# Getting "no serializer found for class" Exception in restAssured post request

Tags: api, rest-assured

I have a Json Payload for a Post call as below:

```
{
  "action" : "Closed",
  "Id" : 30144,
  "expireDate" : null,
  "inputUser" : "abc",
  "previousStatusId" : 1,
  "statusId" : 4,
  "Notes" : [ ]
}
```

My POJO classes for the above payload is as below

```
public class UpdateNoteStatus {
    
    private String action;
    private int Id;
    private String expireDate;
    private String inputUser;
    private int previousStatusId;
    private int statusId;
    private List<Notes> Notes;
    
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }
    public void setExpireDate(String expireDate) {
        this.expireDate = expireDate;
    }
    public void setinputUser(String inputUser) {
        this.inputUser = inputUser;
    }
    public void setPreviousStatusId(int previousStatusId) {
        this.previousStatusId = previousStatusId;
    }
    public void setStatusId(int statusId) {
        this.statusId = statusId;
    }
    public void setNotes(List<Notes> Notes) {
        this.Notes = Notes;
    }

}

public class Notes{
}
```

Now I have assigned the values in the main class from where I am making the API call is as below:

```
ArrayList<Notes> Notes = new ArrayList<Notes>();

    UpdateNoteStatus objUpdateNoteStatus = new UpdateNoteStatus();
    objUpdateNoteStatus.setAction("Closed");
    objUpdateNoteStatus.setId(Integer.parseInt("30144"));
    objUpdateNoteStatus.setinputUser("abc");
    objUpdateNoteStatus.setPreviousStatusId(1);
    objUpdateNoteStatus.setStatusId(4);
    objUpdateNoteStatus.setNotes(Notes);
```

But when I am making the API POST call it is throwing exception - "no serializer found for class and no properties discovered to create beanserializer". Could you please help. The Step is hightlighted in Bold.

```
RequestSpecification rs = given().contentType("application/json");

**rs = rs.body(objUpdateNoteStatus);** //In This Step I am getting the above mentioned Exception

Response res = rs.when().post("/UpdateStatus");
```

Answer (score 1):

as you are initializing an empty object , you need to use below Annotation supported in below library
com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
class UpdateNoteStatus
```